Why can't I get the value of a pytorch tensor on TPU on Google Colab
I Google ColabI can't get the value of a PyTorch tensor that is on the TPU and requires_grad.
When I write in Google Colab :
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
device = xm.xla_device()

t = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True).to(device)
print(t)

It's ok but if I do:

import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
device = xm.xla_device()

t1 = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True).to(device)
t2 = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True).to(device)
t3 = t1 + t2
print(t3)

Colab freezes indefinitely it also happens when I use t.item() or t.cpu().item() I need this to get the value out of the tensor.
